# Identify the top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right position of a rectangle in Swift (elegant solution)

Tags: swift

I'd like to find an elegant solution to identify the corners of a rectangle given a list of points (that I'm sure will define a rectangle).

Let's say we have this array of `CGPoint`:

```
var points:[CGPoint] = []
points.append(CGPoint(x:1, y:0)) //TL
points.append(CGPoint(x:3, y:0)) //TR
points.append(CGPoint(x:1, y:2)) //BL
points.append(CGPoint(x:3, y:2)) //BR
```

Which would be an elegant solution to understand that TopLeft corner is at index 0, Top Right at index 1... and so on?

I could cycle through the array multiple times and find it using a comparison... can you think at a better solution maybe using `sort` or `filter` ?

EDIT: Please note that the points array is unordered. I don't have a precise sequence of points.

Comment: @matt No, there's no code to review.

Comment: Yes, that’s another problem with the question.

Comment: Should I delete it?

Comment: Plus the code you actually gave doesn't even compile.

Comment: Plus "elegant" is a matter of opinion...

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answers you got, you should mark this question as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are Core Graphics structs, so ask Core Graphics to help you. Construct a path from any point through each of the other points in any order and ask for its bounding box. Now you have a CGRect whose corner points are your points, but now you know which is which, and matching them up to yours is trivial.

Example:

```
    var points:[CGPoint] = []
    points.append(CGPoint(x:1, y:0)) //TL
    points.append(CGPoint(x:3, y:0)) //TR
    points.append(CGPoint(x:1, y:2)) //BL
    points.append(CGPoint(x:3, y:2)) //BR

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: points[0])
    for ix in 1...3 {path.addLine(to: points[ix])}
    let rect = path.boundingBox
```

The answer is `CGRect(x:1.0, y:0.0, width:2.0, height:2.0)` and now you know its `minX`, `minY`, `maxX`, and `maxY` and can easily match those up to your original points.

And you get the same result regardless of the order in which the points were supplied.

Comment: how could I obtain a rectangle path starting from an unordered list of points? I do not know which is the right sequence to add lines to the path to obtain the rectangles... points might be listed in any order. (I'm updating my question... it wasn't clear)

Comment: It doesn't need to be a rectangle path. That's the _point_ of my answer. Core Graphics _gives_ you the rectangle path.

Comment: Ohhh I see your point! using the bounding box you obtain the rectangle. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can use map / reduce to achieve relatively simple syntax.  Assuming:

```
    var points: [CGPoint] = []
    points.append(CGPoint(x: 3, y: 6))
    points.append(CGPoint(x: 4, y: 6))
    points.append(CGPoint(x: 4, y: 2))
    points.append(CGPoint(x: 3, y: 2))
```

You can then:

```
    let minX = points.map { $0.x } .reduce(points[0].x) { min($0,$1) }
```

At which point minX = 3. You could also use a sorted(by:)

```
    let minX = points.sorted { $0.x < $1.x }.first!.x
```

Both have the advantages of working on any shape built from points. Matt also suggested using min() on the array, which looks like this:

```
    let minX = points.min { $0.x < $1.x }!.x
```

I guess that's as clean as can be.

Oh, one more for the books... if you are going to be converting points to CGRect in a lot of places.. you can create yourself a CGRect extension:

```
extension CGRect {
    init(from points: [CGPoint]) {
        let xAxis = points.sorted { $0.x < $1.x }
        let yAxis = points.sorted { $0.y < $1.y }
        self.init(x: xAxis.first!.x, y: yAxis.first!.y, width: xAxis.last!.x - xAxis.first!.x, height: yAxis.last!.y - yAxis.first!.y)
    }
}
```

Which you can then use with:

```
let rect = CGRect(from: points)
// rect.minX
```

Cheers!

Comment: Really? Not `min(where:)`?

Comment: You probably mean min(by:) ? ;)